# Função para inverter vetor c

Tags: c, funções

Sou um iniciante em c e gostaria de saber o que está acontecendo de errado nesse meu código. Sei que fiz uma maracutaia na função, mas foi onde cheguei mais perto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inverte(int vetor_A[ ], int posicao)
{
    int auxiliar, tamanho_vetor = posicao - 1;

    for (posicao = 0; posicao <= tamanho_vetor; posicao++)
    {
      auxiliar = vetor_A[posicao];
      vetor_A[posicao] = vetor_A[tamanho_vetor];
      vetor_A[tamanho_vetor] = auxiliar;
      tamanho_vetor--;
      printf("%d ", vetor_A[posicao]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vetor_A[3], posicao;

    for (posicao = 0; posicao < 3; posicao++)
    {
        printf("Entre com os valores:\n");
        scanf(" %d", &vetor_A[posicao]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    inverte(vetor_A, posicao);

    return 0;
}
```

Ele imprime isso:

> Entre com os valores:
>   3
>   Entre com os valores:
>   4
>   Entre com os valores:
>   5
>    5  4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O teu algoritmo está correto. Ele só tá imprimindo metade do vetor, pois o `for` dentro da função `inverte` só percorre até o meio.

Você pode imprimir depois desse loop ou colocar na função main depois de chamar o `inverte`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inverte(int vetor_A[ ], int posicao)
{
    int auxiliar, tamanho_vetor = posicao - 1;

    for (posicao = 0; posicao <= tamanho_vetor; posicao++)
    {
      auxiliar = vetor_A[posicao];
      vetor_A[posicao] = vetor_A[tamanho_vetor];
      vetor_A[tamanho_vetor] = auxiliar;
      tamanho_vetor--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vetor_A[3], posicao;

    for (posicao = 0; posicao < 3; posicao++)
    {
        printf("Entre com os valores:\n");
        scanf(" %d", &vetor_A[posicao]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    inverte(vetor_A, posicao);

    int tamanho = posicao;
    for (posicao = 0; posicao < tamanho; posicao++)
    {
        printf("%d ", vetor_A[posicao]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Então, agora compreendi, segui sua dica e imprimi no main. Mas pensando agora, não seria errado tentar imprimir dentro da função já que ela é do tipo void, logo, não retornando nada? Eu tentei imprimir após o loop na função e deu o mesmo erro de antes.

Comment: Você armazenou o tamanho do vetor antes dos loops? Pois no seu código depois de executar o primeiro loop dentro do `inverte` as variáveis `posicao` e `tamanho` sempre terminam com o valor 1 (meio do vetor).

Comment: Ah, sim. Agora entendi. Muito obrigado.